# during ubuntu 14.04 installation mistake

Tags: 14.04

I accidently removed the installation cd during installation. Installation was stopped and nothing happened. I took power of and on and now only my cursor is flashing on the left upcorner of my screen. whatever bottom i push , nothing happens. I have the installation cd in but nothing happens. Only the cursor is flashing. I think  am in trouble. This is my friends laptop.

Comment: Just boot again from installation CD and install Ubuntu from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm figuring the computer is looking to boot to the internal hard disk, instead of the CD, if it thinks there's something installed on the hard disk. Try getting to the boot menu at the BIOS before it boots anything (usually, something like pushing F12 right as the computer is booting until it takes you to a boot menu). It may be a different key for your model, but the principle remains the same.